# Kubernetes Deployment failure after only few resources are created

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubectl

I have been trying Kubernetes deployment using helm. I had deployed it before and it had worked previously, now facing issues in which only a few pods are running and deployment fails after that.

getting the following error in events :

```
MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "config-volume" : failed to sync configmap cache: timed out waiting for the condition
MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "istiod-ca-cert" : failed to sync configmap cache: timed out waiting for the condition
MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "istiod-ca-cert" : configmap "istio-ca-root-cert" not found
```

Comment: Check the logs from your kube-apiserver.

Comment: Hi,thanks for the response. Could you please tell me how to do that ?

Comment: It depends on how you're running Kubernetes.

Comment: getting logs from kube-api below is what i Observed
'http: TLS handshake error from 10.0.12.18:58977: tls: client offered only unsupported versions: [300] '

Any idea on how this can be fixed ?

Comment: Did you install a really old version of Istio?